# JAVAFX == > Can i used the POJO class's object in SceneBuilder edited FXML 's controller class of fxml?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

i am new to javaFX but have good knowledge in java.

Coz i got the runtime error of loadException when i used the other normal java class's object in controller class of fxml.otherwise its run properly. But i want other plain java class's functionality in controller class,then i got runtime exception...plz help me..
Thanks.
1>>>

```
package test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable ;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import model.AdminDB;


public class KkController implements Initializable ,controlscreen  {

    AdminDB a=new AdminDB(); // i can't able to create the object here in controller class

 public ScreenController mycontroller;
 public static TextField username,psw;
        // 
    public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        mycontroller.setScreen(Test.screen2Id);

    }


    public void onuserclick(ActionEvent event)  {
      try
      { 

     System.out.println("error==");
   //  a.createuser();

     //  a.grantuser();
      }catch(Exception ae)
      {
          System.out.println("error=="+ae);
      } 
    }



    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreenController s) {
      mycontroller=s;  
    }    
}
```

Comment: What's the error? You should see a stack trace further down with useful information (i.e. what caused the load exception).

Comment: hello sir,I think,i am new to javaFX nd try to use normal java program as a business logic and javaFX as Frontend.. just want to ask can i used that java class's object in the controller class. thanks

Comment: Yes. The controller is just a Java class like any other. You can create objects and call methods on those objects.